# Plugin in object literal syntax has problems with $

Tags: jquery, syntax, object-literal

I have a plugin written in object literal syntax, so it's a basically just a large object variable. Its in an external JS file. When I initialize that function inline in my html within in a 
 `jQuery(document).ready(function($){}`  function, I get this error: "Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function".

If I change all the "$" in the plugin file to "jQuery" it works. Is there a way to get the plugin to work without doing that though? Thanks! Let me know if you need more info/code to help me, I can provide more.

--More details:

Its a plugin to limit the characters on a input/textarea. It looks like this:

```
var charLimiter = { 
  //config stuff here...

'init' : function(options) {    
        if (options && typeof(options) == 'object') {
             $.extend(charLimiter.config, options);
        }

    $('.'+charLimiter.config.inputClass).each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);

       charLimiter.appendHTML($this);
       charLimiter.calcChars($this); 
    });

},

'someFunction' : function(){}, 

//..more stuff here... 

};
```

When I call in in HTML it looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   charLimiter.init();
});
```

Comment: That most likely depends on how you wrote the plugin.  Can you show us that?

Comment: Its a plugin to limit the characters on a input/textarea. I just edited my post to show more detail, Explosion Pills

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the plugin with following:

```
;(function($){    
/* plugin code here can use "$"*/
})(jQuery);
```

This would work if plugin references `$.fn.pluginName` or `$.pluginName` May not work if not, would need to see how plugin is constructed